# VBA: Can't assign ppAutoSizeMixed to TextBox.TextFrame.AutoSize

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I am writing a VBA application in PowerPoint2010 which adds different shapes and name them automatically.

Now I am trying to change the Textbox.TextFrame.AutoSize property which have three possible values: -2, 0 and 1.

If I try to assign ppAutoSizeMixed with VBA I get an "out of range" exception. 0 and 1 I am able to assign without any trouble.

```
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes(1).TextFrame.AutoSize //-2
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes(1).TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone //0
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes(1).TextFrame.AutoSize 
= ppAutoSizeMixed//-2: exception
```

I am able to change the value with PowerPoint but not with VBA. Do someone know this issue and know how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: -2 / Mixed is what PPT hands back when, for example, a text range has bold applied to some of the range but not all.  Applying it as a property doesn't make sense.  Applying mixed formatting to an object will turn the value for that property to mixed though.  In the case of AutoSize, what would you expect setting it to Mixed to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want to archieve is that the font is resized automatically if the text in the box is getting longer. I thought by setting AutoSize to ppAutoSizeMixed this is possible but now I understand why the value is -2. But isn't there any way to activate the setting with resizing font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here you go:  Assuming a reference to your shape in oSh:

```
With oSh
   .TextFrame2.AutoSize = 2
End With
```